# What is unsigned type we pass to parameter?

Tags: c++, types, unsigned

I have the exercise with following code

```
int FindFirstSet(unsigned BitMap, unsigned start)
{
    unsigned Mask = (1 << start);
    while (Mask)
    {
        if (BitMap & Mask) return start;
        ++start;
        Mask <<= 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The question is :

"The C++ programming language does not specify how many bits there are in an unsigned
integer. Explain why the code above will work regardless of the number of bits in an
unsigned integer."

Follow this question, could I think that: any type of "Bitmap parameter" was, the "start parameter" also have Bitmap's type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All parameters and variables are unsigned int.

Comment: ohh, very simple answer but its correct ;), thanks you so much?

Answer (score 1):

This code will work because `Mask` and `BitMap` have the same length, and max possible value for `start` is greater than the length of `BitMap`.

But this code will not always work as expected. Here is what c++ standard says about shift operators:
`The behavior is undefined if the right operand
is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.`

So it is possible that on some compilers we'll see that `FindFirstSet(1, 42)` returns 42 instead of -1.